# Visual Studio Online - Get Latest and NuGet

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015, nuget, azure-devops

It's very possible that I'm missing something simple because I can't find others on the internet experiencing the same thing.

I'm a team that's new to the use of TFS and Visual Studio Online and we're encountering this problem:

(Using Visual Studio 2015 & 2013)

1. I used NuGet to add Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors to my newly created WebAPI project (ditto all other NuGet packages)
2. Did my work and checked in a building solution in to VSO
3. Co-worker did a Get Latest
4. His newly-retrieved project won't build and, when we expand the References, the assemblies are marked with a yellow warning icon, indicating that they're missing

We've tried (from the context of the failing project):

1. Update-Package
2. Update-Package -reinstall
3. Manually uninstalling and reinstalling the package in the NuGet UI
4. Manually adding the entire contents of the Packages directory in to TFS and doing a get latest on that directory as well
5. Wiping the solution out from his local file system and pulling it down clean
6. Copying the contents of my {Solution Directory}\Packages to a USB drive, walking it to my co-worker's computer, and copying it to his machine

Only item #6 worked but I'm CERTAIN that this cannot be the right answer.

I guarantee that this is worthy of a dope-slap but what might I be missing?

Comment: Is your packages.config file in source control?

Comment: Is your coworker getting any NuGet errors? Can your coworker create a brand new WebAPI project plus WebApi.Cors package? Is this working? Is NuGet set to restore packages in Visual Studio? Should be on by default.

Comment: No, yes, and yes.

Glad I'm not the only one this has stumped!

Comment: I have the same issue and am also stumped

Comment: Looking at your Source Control folders? What folders are actually checked in? NuGet uses some interesting ways to "detect" that a package has been installed and extracted. Generally having no packages folder at all in source control is better than having one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to jessehouwing for reminding me that this topic is still out here. He's exactly right on. We removed the Packages folder from source control and that resolved the problem completely.